# EventID 4740 report using powershell and suppress email delivery if empty

Tags: powershell

I have a script that gets all the information from the security log and has the event ID 4740. It then creates an html report from that and emails it. What I want to do is to exit the script if there is no data returned from $event.

```
# Created by Brad Tostenson 1/13/17
# This script will gather all the events with event ID 4740 (Account Locked Out)
# creates a report in HTML and emails it to the System Admins as the body
# of the email.

# Varaible the sets the reports temporary location
$LockedOut= "c:\temp\LockedOut.html"

# Setup date
$Date = Get-Date

# Sets up the report 
$HTML=@" 
<title>Account locked out Report</title> 
<!--mce:0--> 
"@ 

# Setup variables for the information to go under the headers in the report 
$Account_Name = @{n='Account Name';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-1]}} 
$Account_domain = @{n='Account Domain';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-2]}} 
$Caller_Computer_Name = @{n='Caller Computer Name';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-1]}} 

   # Pulls the information from the log             
$event = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4740 -after $date.AddHours(-24) | 
   Select TimeGenerated,ReplacementStrings,"Account Name","Account Domain","Caller Computer Name" | 
   % { 
     New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
      "Account Name" = $_.ReplacementStrings[-7] 
      "Account Domain" = $_.ReplacementStrings[5] 
      "Caller Computer Name" = $_.ReplacementStrings[1] 
      Date = $_.TimeGenerated 
    } 
   } 

  $event | ConvertTo-Html -Property "Account Name","Account Domain","Caller Computer Name",Date -head $HTML -body  "<H2> The Following User Accounts Were Locked In Active Directory</H2>"| 
     Out-File $LockedOut -Append 

# Takes the report and adds the information to the body of the email and sends it to the System Admins 
$MailBody= Get-Content $LockedOut 
$MailSubject= "Account Lock Report" 
$SmtpClient = New-Object system.net.mail.smtpClient 
$SmtpClient.host = "smtp.ourdomain.com" 
$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
$MailMessage.from = "LockedOut@ourdomain.com" 
$MailMessage.To.add("email@ourdomain.com") 
$MailMessage.Subject = $MailSubject 
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = 1 
$MailMessage.Body = $MailBody 
$SmtpClient.Send($MailMessage) 

del c:\temp\LockedOut.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why `$event` wouldn't be null if `Get-EventLog` returns no data, and null has a Boolean value of false.  That means you can just do this:

```
if (!$event) { exit }
```

Or, if it makes more sense, you can do this:

```
if ($event) {

      $event | ConvertTo-Html -Property "Account Name","Account Domain","Caller Computer Name",Date -head $HTML -body  "<H2> The Following User Accounts Were Locked In Active Directory</H2>"| 
         Out-File $LockedOut -Append 

    # Takes the report and adds the information to the body of the email and sends it to the System Admins 
    $MailBody= Get-Content $LockedOut 
    $MailSubject= "Account Lock Report" 
    $SmtpClient = New-Object system.net.mail.smtpClient 
    $SmtpClient.host = "smtp.ourdomain.com" 
    $MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
    $MailMessage.from = "LockedOut@ourdomain.com" 
    $MailMessage.To.add("email@ourdomain.com") 
    $MailMessage.Subject = $MailSubject 
    $MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = 1 
    $MailMessage.Body = $MailBody 
    $SmtpClient.Send($MailMessage) 

    del c:\temp\LockedOut.html

}
```

Also, you might want to look at using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet.  It's much simpler that what you're doing.

You also don't technically need the `$LockedOut` file at all, but I'm guessing you're using that in case the network is down or the email fails for some reason.

Comment: I see what you did there and I like it better than the solution that I came up with. So after I have it get-eventlog I just put a line in that says !$event  {Exit}